# Difference in const qualifiers warning

Tags: c, char, constants, warnings

I am getting a bunch of warning messages telling me that

```
Warning C4090   '=': different 'const' qualifiers   cA4  c:\users\kyle\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\ca4\ca4\ca4.c  313
```

I need to compile my code to have no warnings for this school assignment. Everything works okay but I want to know why this is happening. I am assigning a "string" which is really a char* to a value from a const array to keep track of what city they are currently in.

Like so:

```
char* currentCityName = cityNames[currentCity];
```

The warning is occurring on this line later in the program:

```
currentCityName = cityNames[currentCity];
```

Declaration of cityNames:

```
const char* cityNames[kNumberOfCities] = { "Toronto", "Atlanta", "Austin", "Santa Fe", "Denver", "Chicago", "Buffalo" };
```

Clearly some way that I am setting this variable is incorrect and the compiler isnt liking it.

Im looking for an explanation of why this is happening and what I should be doing instead of this.

Comment: What is the declaration of `cityNames`?

Comment: It will be so much easier if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A working example doesnt really seem necessary as other posters are understanding what I am asking..

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I am assigning a "string" which is really a char* to a value from a const array

From that and the error message I presume you mean that you have

```
const char *cityNames[<some bound>];
```

which is an array of pointers to strings whose contents are `const`.  If you also have

```
char *currentCityName;
```

and you later try to perform

```
currentCityName = cityNames[currentCity];
```

then the resulting pointer to *modifiable* characters in fact points to characters that elsewhere are declared `const`.  This mismatch may lead to the program, without any other warning, attempting to modify `const` data, with undefined results.

You could clear up that warning by instead declaring `currentCityName` like so:

```
const char *currentCityName;
```

to match the true type of the value you want to assign to it.  Alternatively, you can make a modifiable copy of the city name, and point `currentCityName` at that.  Making a copy is necessary if you want to (safely) modify the pointed-to data.

Comment: The only problem with this is that currentCityName is changed throughout the code, and making it const would disable that

Comment: As I said, if you need to be able to modify the data to which `currentCityName` points then you need to create a modifiable copy of the `const` data and point to the copy.  On the other hand, if you want only to be able change the value of the `currentCityName` pointer itself, to point it at a different name, then declaring it as a pointer to `const` *data* does not interfere with that.

Comment: This is the difference between `const char *currentCityName` and `char * const currentCityName`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that cityNames is declared as const so when you're assigning the value(does not copy contents) it discards the const qualifier.

In other words you cannot change anything in cityNames because of const but you have another pointer, non-const this time and allow you to change data although it was originally marked as const

Comment: Its not changing the data though its purely reading the data. This is why I am confused

Comment: The const is a promise that you will not modify that data and the compiler checks to see if you have kept your promise. When you assign const data to a non-const member the compiler has no way of knowing that the data it holds is actually marked as const somewhere else. In order to get rid of the warning, if you're really not changing the currentCityName data, declare it as const char*